# How to add and remove predefined completers multiple times inside a getCompeltions function in ace editor

Tags: angular6, ace-editor

I am using the ace editor. I have added predefined completers like textCompleter, SnippetCompleter, and keywordCompleter. But I want to filter data based on the context. So I want to add and remove the completers multiple times. But I observed that we could add or remove the completers only once. Can you please help me to remove and add completers many times.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do additional filtering, remove all completers, and add a new completer that detects context.
From this new completer call other completers, and send combined result as a reply from your completer.